# What "helpers" are available to create unit test in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using VS2013, and also have Resharper installed.  I'm using the default MVC application and added the UnitTest project to the solution.

VS automatically sets up a Unit Test for HomeController.cs.  I want to setup Unit tests for AccountController.cs (and other classes as well).

Is there an IDE tool to automatically wire up a default unit test stub?

Comment: I use a [file template](https://gist.github.com/uhaciogullari/6855661#file-nunit-test-fixture-file-template) for creating test fixtures. You may find it useful.